# Auto Updating feature in WSO2 Appmanager and EMM

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

How do App-manager and EMM govern the auto updating feature?

If I update an app, then how will it notify the end user to update their app in the app-manager and in EMM? Can we force the user for to update the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do App-manager and EMM govern the auto updating feature?

Currently there is no auto-update feature available in App manager and EMM. After uploading an app you will have to manually apply the update on the devices. However, if the user who is enrolled with EMM, belongs to a role, it is possible to send the update to the whole role without having to manually go thought each user/device. 
Not directly related but, with the upcoming release of EMM 2.1.0, there will be a scheduled update/install feature, which enables you to specify the time a certain app must be updated.

> If I update an app, then how will it notify the end user to update
>   their app in the app-manager and in EMM?

End user will get a pop up(The usual install app popup of OS) telling user to install/update the app

> Can we force the user for to update the app?

This is not available in 2.0.1
With EMM 2.1.0, in order to force user to install an app, you will need to have the ability to silently install an app. This can be done, if the catalog application is vendor signed to make it a system application. Or else, if you are a OEM, agent can be made a system app.

Comment: When will be the new versions of App-manager and EMM will be released?